# $.ajax works when immediately invoked, but not when invoked as a callback on click

Tags: jquery, ajax

When getWeather() is invoked on its own on page load, the API call and writing the response to the DOM works. But if I call getWeather on a button click, nothing happens (no error in console).

```
  const submitButton = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
  const max = document.querySelector('.max');

  getWeather = () => {   
    $.ajax(weatherEndpoint)
       .then(function(response) {
          //response  
          const maxTemp = response.main.temp_max;
          //write response to DOM
          max.innerText = maxTemp;
        });
      }

  //this works:        
  getWeather()  

 //this does not work:
 //submitButton.addEventListener("click", getWeather )
```

Comment: If the button is part of a form then change the type to `type="button"` or better use the `submit` event of the form where you can prevent the submission of the form. Otherwise the form gets submitted, which in this case will reload the page.

Comment: And please add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `jquery` you could just use [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) to attach the event to the button:

```
$(submitButton).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    getWeather();
});
```

If `submitButton` is in a form and it is `type="submit"` then it will submit the form to the server.  To stop this use `e.preventDefault()`;

You should able to add this to your code:

```
getWeather = (e) => {  
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax(weatherEndpoint)
       .then(function(response) {
          //response  
          const maxTemp = response.main.temp_max;
          //write response to DOM
          max.innerText = maxTemp;
    });
}
```

and call with `submitButton.addEventListener("click", getWeather );`.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned

```
//this does not work:
 //submitButton.addEventListener("click", getWeather )
```

try this from below

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(getWeather);
```

and then remove the line

```
getWeather();
```

Comment: What would be the difference? O.o

Comment: He has mentioned in the last line of question,

Comment: that  this is not working //submitButton.addEventListener("click", getWeather )

Comment: addEventListener do not work, until that element is added in DOM. So try using Jquery event listener.